# Why am I getting this error inside a function /* SQL Error (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s) */

Tags: mysql

Why am I getting `/* SQL Error (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s) */` here.

**Here's my function create**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `newLink`(`encAction` VARCHAR(27))
    RETURNS varchar(512)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

RETURN ('{"actVal":"',encAction,'"}');//I'm going wrong somewhere here.

END
```

**Here's how I call it**

```
select newLink(1);
```

I'm actually passing `encAction`, but seem to be failing. This same thing works in a `SQL` statement, but fails inside a function. Do you see why and how to get this right?

Comment: Was it your intention to concatenate those strings?

Comment: I'll encrypt them later. It's a large string. This is just one val for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string values need to be concatenated. Instead of this:

```
RETURN ('{"actVal":"',encAction,'"}');
```

Try this:

```
RETURN CONCAT('{"actVal": "', encAction, '"}');
```

This assumes you're trying to return a JSON-ish value such as `{"actVal": "foo"}`.

Comment: You;re right. It is Json. But aren't the `" "` needed for `actVal`?

Comment: You're right. The quotes are needed; I slipped into JavaScript mode :) I'll update my answer.